# Use of custom parameters in functions and procedures in pascal

Tags: function, pascal, procedure, optional-parameters

Can I leave some of the **Pascal** custom `functions` or `procedure` parameters `blank`? if this is possible, how should I do?

For e.g. like **Google's App** script `newBlob()`, I can fill in one or more `parameters` but it is not a must to fill in all `parameters`

I'm using *Dev-Pas*
with *FPC* compiler

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any answer will depend on the specific Pascal dialect you're using. Standard Pascal does not allow optional parameters. Please add a tag for the specific compiler you're using.

Comment: The website says Dev-Pas uses FreePascal or GNU Pascal. Which one are you using?

Comment: Yes, but one page said it uses an ancient FreePascal, not the latest. So it is still not sure they are supported.

Comment: Afaik devpascal uses FPC 1.9.2 which afaik supports default parameters.

Comment: Assume it can leave some parameters blank, how can I leave some parameters blank? By directly using a space to leave it blank or other ways?

Comment: *If* the variant of Pascal you are using supports default parameters, you leave it blank by omitting it. Note that if you have an default parameter, it must be the last parameter. If you have more than one, they must all be at the end of the list of parameters, and you can't pick and choose which to omit. If you omit one, you must omit all those that come after it. That's pretty typical of most languages that support default parameters. See [Default parameter](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Default_parameter) (link obtained by a quick Google search of "free pascal default paramters").

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question.

But maybe you are talking about MyProc() vs. MyProc?

If so, there is no need to write the () in fpc if there are no params required.

e.g.:

function MyProc : string;
function MyProc( DoPrint : boolean = true ) : string;

Both can simply be called as 'MyProc', unless you don't want #2 to print. Then it would be: MyProc( false );

HTH